# Modal não abre no segundo clique

Tags: jquery, modal

Tenho o seguinte botão:

```
<button class="btn btn-default botao_leitura_biometrica" id="" style='border: solid 1px #666'>Lectura Biométrica</button>
```

Isto, deverá abrir uma modal:

```
    <div class="modal modal-lg leitura_biometrica_modal" id="leitura_biometrica_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index: 99999 !important;">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title titulo-modal" id="myModalLabel">Busquéda por Lectura Biométrica</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body conteudo-modal-pesquisa">
                    Coloque o dedão
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancelar" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Pesquisar agora!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Até ai, ok! No primeiro clique, abriu normalmente.
Cliquei no botão fechar, e cliquei novamente para abrir.

E ao clicar na segunda ou próximas vezes antes do reload, aparece o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Este é o jQuery de abertura:

```
$(".botao_leitura_biometrica").click(function(){
    $(".leitura_biometrica_modal").modal('show');
    var url = BASE_URL + 'ajax/pesquisar_digital';
    $(".conteudo-modal-pesquisa").load(url);            
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta usando Bootstrap, não precisa criar uma função em js para abrir seu modal, pois o próprio Bootstrap já oferece isso.
Para essa sua modal o botão ficaria assim:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#leitura_biometrica_modal">
  Lectura Biométrica
</button>
```

Comment: Ok, amigo, abrir ele abre. Porém, os botões de cancelar e fechar não funciona mais... Talvez seja algo da modal?

Comment: Era algo da minha modal, peguei o exemplo prático mesmo, agora deu certo, vou aplicar a função do load pra ver.. :)

Comment: Perfeito Era isso, obrigado!